# Which scripture mention an encounter between Ravana and Ikshvaku king Raghu?

Tags: ravana, war

This [website](https://naidunia.jagran.com/spiritual/kehte-hain-ravan-ego-chef-raghu-broken-arrow-147791) mention that Lord Rama's ancestor Mahārāja Raghu used Narayanastra on Ravana.

Was there an encounter between them? Where is the story can be found?

Answer (score 1):

According to Valmiki Ramayana, battle did not take place between Raghu of Ikshvaku dynasty and Ravana.

However, battle did  take place between **Anaranya** of Ikshvaku dynasty and Ravana.  This was mentioned by Ravana himself after the 1st encounter with Sri Rama in which he was defeated and was spared by Sri Rama.

> विदितम् मानुषम् मन्ये रामं दशरथात्मजम् |
>   इक्ष्वाकुकुलजातेन **अनर्ण्येन** यत् पुरा || ६-६०-८
>   उत्पत्स्यति हि मद्वंशे पुरुषो राक्षसाधम |
>   यस्त्वाम् सपुत्रम् सामात्यम् सबलम् साश्वसारथिम् || ६-६०-९
>   निहनिष्यति सम्ग्रामे त्वाम् कुलाधम दुर्मते |
>
> "Rama the son of Dasaratha is the man I think of whom **Anaranya born of Ikshvaku dynasty** formerly spoke, saying: 'O, the worst of demons, the worst of your race and the wretched one! In my race will be born a man who will slay you in battle with your sons, ministers, army, horses and charioteer."

Comment: Thanks but answer to this Q is not restricted till Valmiki Ramayana. I want to know if this is discussed in any scripture. BDW, othr than Anaranya, Ravan had battle with Mandhata (Valmiki Ramayana-Uttar kanada) and with Dasratha (Anand Ramayana) as well.

Comment: @YDS: According to my analysis, Uttara Kanda is an interpolation.  So my answers will be based on the Ramayana upto Yuddha Kanda only.:-)