# Did Ravana ever attack the Ikshvaku king Dasharatha?

Tags: ramayana, ravana

During the final stages of the great war, between Lord Sri Rama(and army consisting of brother Lakshmana and vanaras) and Ravana( and his demon soldiers), Ravana could foresee his final defeat at the hands of Lord Sri Rama. Ravana addressed his demon soldiers and told them about his fears. And during that address Ravana mentioned about a curse that he had received from Ikshvaku king Anaranya:-

> Rama the son of Dasaratha is the man I think of whom Anaranya born of Ikshvaku dynasty formerly spoke, saying: 'O, the worst of demons, the worst of your race and the wretched one! In my race will be born a man who will slay you in battle with your sons, ministers, army, horses and charioteer."

Shlokas 6-60-8,and 9.

Ikshvaku was the first king who executed the Manusmrti or religious rules of Hindu living which were composed by his father Manu. Ikshvaku, ruled as Monarch at the beginning of the Satya Yuga or First Yuga.

King Anaranya (also Anena) was the third Ikshvaku king after king Ikshvaku.And king Dasharatha and Sri Rama, were the 60th and 61st respectively. So apparently,Ravana attacked king Anaranya,a long long time ago.

Did Ravana attack subsequent Ikshvaku kings after king Anaranya? Did Ravana ever attack the Ikshvaku king Dasharatha?

Comment: Related (not duplicate): https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/27994/12304 https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24750/12304

Comment: "cursed by king Anaranya...and...Ravana...would "have thought"... of making more attacks on Ikshvaku kings"- Yes, true... "i feel...something has scared Ravana off!" No, he was so arrogant...after reading https://mnaidunia.jagran.com/spiritual/kehte-hain-ravan-ego-chef-raghu-broken-arrow-147791 it seems he continued attacking all kings after Anaranya.. conflict bw Mandhata is mentioned in above comment...this link mention about Raghu.. my grandfather tells some story of conflict bw Ravana & Dashrath too, not sure if it has any scriptural references or just folk lore...

Answer (score 4):

There is no evidence of an encounter with Dasharatha
The claim of Dasharatha defeating Ravana **comes from this fictional book**: [History of the Earth](https://books.google.com/books?id=BmCKBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=Dasaratha%20defeated%20Ravana&source=bl&ots=kuZeW0V9rm&sig=ACfU3U0jhdqmmBVy4JV2mgPFBBohnyJmlA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiboKff-JzlAhUMs54KHeiyB8QQ6AEwEXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Dasaratha%20defeated%20Ravana&f=false)

This is what Dasharatha tells people about Ravana in the ***actual ramayana*** :

> Thus when he is said so by that sage Vishvamitra, then the king Dasharatha spoke to the sage, "I myself am not capable of standing against that evil minded Ravana, in truth, where is the question of deputing my young Rama to confront him? [1-20-20]

[Bala Kandam](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga20/bala_20_frame.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The encounter between Raavana and Dasaratha is mentioned in [Aananda Raamaayana: Saara Kaanda: Sarga 1](https://archive.org/details/HindiBookAnandRamayan/page/n18):

> Ravana calls for Brahma and asks Him who will cause his (Ravana's)
>   death.  Brahma tells him that Lord Narayana will be born to Dasaratha 
>   and Kausalya as Rama and will kill Ravana.  He also tells him
>   that Dasaratha and Kausalya are going to be married in 5 days.
>
> Ravana gets on his pushpaka vimana with several asuras and goes to Ayodhya,
>   fights with Dasaratha and breaks the boat Dasaratha is in.  Dasaratha and
>   Sumantra somehow escape holding on to a piece of the boat and float down 
>   the Sarayu river, reach the Ganges and eventually the ocean. ~[English translation source](https://ramanuja.org/sri/BhaktiListArchives/Article?p=apr97%2F0052.html)

---

**Related posts**

[Why did Ravana abduct lord Rama's mother Kausalya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31489/why-did-ravana-abduct-lord-ramas-mother-kausalya/31532#31532)

[Was there an encounter between Ravana and Ikshvaku king Māndhātā?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24750/was-there-an-encounter-between-ravana-and-ikshvaku-king-m%c4%81ndh%c4%81t%c4%81/24762#24762)

[Which scripture mention an encounter between Ravana and Ikshvaku king Raghu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27994/which-scripture-mention-an-encounter-between-ravana-and-ikshvaku-king-raghu)